# Set text colour of a disabled JSpinner (to make it easier to read)

Tags: java, swing, properties, textcolor

```
JSpinner waitHr  = new JSpinner();
waitHr.setEnabled(false);
```

I have a spinner and I need to prevent the user from editing it temporarily. The problem is, when the spinner is disabled, it's text colour makes it very hard to read, which is not acceptable in this case. I noticed that you can do this with `JTextField`s:

```
 JTextField txtTest   = new JTextField();
 txtTest.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Is there anything similar that can be used for a JSpinner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can play with that as you want

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class InactiveBackgroundTest {

    public JComponent makeUI() {
        JSpinner s0 = new JSpinner();
        s0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        s0.setEnabled(false);
        UIManager.put("FormattedTextField.inactiveBackground", Color.RED);
        JSpinner s1 = new JSpinner();
        s1.setEnabled(false);
        s1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        JSpinner s2 = new JSpinner();
        s2.setEnabled(false);
        s2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        JTextField field = ((JSpinner.NumberEditor) s2.getEditor()).getTextField();
        field.setEditable(false);
        field.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("FormattedTextField.background"));
        JSpinner s3 = new JSpinner();
        s3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        s3.setEnabled(false);
        s3.setBorder(null);
        JTextField tf = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) s3.getEditor()).getTextField();
        tf.setDisabledTextColor(Color.black);
        tf.setBackground(Color.white);
        tf.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue, 1));
        s3.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 1));
        int n = s3.getComponentCount();
        if (n > 0) {
            Component[] components = s3.getComponents();
            String compName = "";
            for (int i = 0, l = components.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (components[i] instanceof JButton) {
                    JButton button = (JButton) components[i];
                    if (button.hasFocus()) {
                        String btnMane = button.getName();
                    }
                    button.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 1));
                    System.out.println("JButton");
                } else if (components[i] instanceof JComboBox) {
                    System.out.println("JComboBox");
                } else if (components[i] instanceof JTextField) {
                    System.out.println("JTextField");
                } else if (components[i] instanceof JFormattedTextField) {
                    System.out.println("JFormattedTextField");
                } else if (components[i] instanceof JTable) {
                    System.out.println("JTable");
                } else if (components[i] instanceof JScrollPane) {
                    System.out.println("JScrollPane");
                } else if (components[i] instanceof JPanel) {
                    JPanel panel = (JPanel) components[i];
                    panel.setBackground(Color.red);
                    panel.setBorder(null);
                    System.out.println("JPanel");
                }
            }
        }
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(Color.black);
        p.add(s0);
        p.add(s1);
        p.add(s2);
        p.add(s3);
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        try {
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo laf : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(laf.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf.getClassName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new InactiveBackgroundTest().makeUI());
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 140));
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [getTextField()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.DefaultEditor.html#getTextField%28%29) method of `JSpinner.DefaultEditor`.

Comment: in due to respect to your person nobody knows, when you needed that :-)  http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9337792&#9337792 :-) , pfuuuuj really crossUpVoters

Comment: @mKorbel: Good reference link. I'm sorry, but I don't understand "pfuuuuj really crossUpVoters." Can you elaborate?

Comment: @mKorbel: Ah, thank you. In English, the word "cross" can also mean "annoyed"; I'm glad you were _not_ cross with me. :-) I was pleased to cross-vote your answer, and I agree completely with @David's choice. There's even a [Sportsmanship](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship) badge for up-voting competing answers.